# Odoo ERP java API Client with jersey Library

Tags: java, rest, odoo, jersey-client

Java API Client for Odoo API not working while adding session_id in the header.

My code is here.
I am using Java jersey Library

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(getUrl);ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .header("session_id", "615a0000df586b9dbbea4c06f91fb1454dbf1525").type("application/json")
                .post(ClientResponse.class, jsonReq);
String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

---------------------------- out put ---------------

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:563)
at com.peapi.zbz.sarmix.restclient.JerseyClientPost.getList1(JerseyClientPost.java:154)
at com.peapi.zbz.sarmix.restclient.JerseyClientPost.main(JerseyClientPost.java:39)
```

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

[image: image of api test tool]

i need add the session id in my post request using jersey java rest client

Comment: I got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

yes I got the solution

```
String sessionId = "ee5c5b33590ce7c1ebb3ea55ce1bbed37b11614a";
        final String urlAuth = "http://testsssssxxx.com/web/dataset/call";
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(urlAuth);
        final String input = "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"params\": { \"model\": \"auto.wbr.conf\", \"method\": \"api_get_supp_trans\", \"args\": [{\"wbr_sequence\": \"1234\",\"factory_id\":\"1\"}] } }";
        ClientResponse response =webResource.type("application/json").header("cookie", "session_id="+sessionId).post(ClientResponse.class,input);
        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
        }

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: .header("cookie", "session_id="+sessionId).post(ClientResponse.class,input)